# Trying to implement JWPlayer in a swift 3 framework

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, jwplayer

I'm actually working on a IOS swift 3 project that is composed of 3 parts.
A framework and two apps. The framework serves as a base for two different apps and contains the majority of the code.

I'm was trying to implement JWPlayer to this base framework but I'm facing a problem during the installation process.

I tried to follow the starter guide but I face two issues.
The first is when I try to set a path to my Bridging Header in `Build Setting` of my framework,I get an error:`using bridging headers with framework targets is unsupported`.

I then tried to set a link to `#import <JWPlayer-SDK/JWPlayerController.h>` in my umbrella header file of my framework but I get a different error message that says `Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'XXXX'`

I'm basically stuck between these two messages and I can't figure out what to do next.

I presume this behavior appeared because I'm trying to implement the JWPlayer in a framework and not a project.

I'm open to any suggestion on how to fix this situation.

Thank you in advance for any help or tips you could give me.

Best regards

Comment: kind of stuck at this point. did u find any solutions .

Comment: For the moment I haven't found a good working solution sorry. I'll keep you posted if I do

Answer (score 0):

May be you miss config in Build Settings part like me . . .
Please see this setting instruction. It works for me.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39615171/1321159