# "Objective-C Bridging Header" entry in Build Settings does not appear in Xcode 8.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode8, build-settings

I need to add some `Objective-C` files of a library to my project, and I created the `MyProject-Bridging-Header.h` file myself. But now I'm not able to set its path because in the project's Build Settings I don't find the `Objective-C Bridging Header` entry.

Is somebody else experiencing the same? How could I solve this?

Comment: Look at "Swift compiler - General" section in your target build setting. Or try to restart your XCode

Answer (score 12):

In Build Setting choose "all" instead of "basic"
[image]

Answer (score 8):

Usually when you had an Objective-C/Swift project and have added new Swift/Objective-C class file Xcode asks whether you want to **create Bridging Header** or not.

- If the option to create **Bridging Header automatically** f.e. has been denied there`s still an option to create it **manually**.
- Since you have already created `YourProject-Bridging-Header.h` header file all you need to set the path to it in your project Build Settings.
- To **set the path to your Bridging Header file** you need to navigate to your project Build Setting where look for **Swift Compiler – General** section like the Hoa mentioned above. 
  It is located between "Swift Compiler - Custom Flags" and "Swift Compiler - Search Paths" ones at the same page with all "Swift Compiler" sections.
- There you can see **Objective-C Bridging Header** which you can click and set the path to your `YourProject-Bridging-Header.h` Bridging Header file like `YourProjectName/YourProject-Bridging-Header.h`.
- Now you can open up your `YourProject-Bridging-Header.h` and put Objective-C/Swift classes using the `#import` statement into it.

Thanks to http://www.learnswiftonline.com/getting-started/adding-swift-bridging-header/ 
And [Objective-C Bridging Header not getting created with Xcode 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39614899/objective-c-bridging-header-not-getting-created-with-xcode-8)

Comment: The thing is that under `Swift Compiler - General` section I only see `Optimization Level`

Comment: That's true, sorry. I meant if you open up the page with `Swift compiler`'s the `Swift Compiler - General` will be a little bit lower than the `Swift Compiler - Code generation` at the same page. You should stick with the `Swift Compiler - General` and check for `Objective-C Bridging Header` there.