# Using Objective-C framework in Swift project

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks

I want to include an Objective-C framework in my Swift project. I followed the instructions to append my existing pod file and executed

```
pod update
```

The files were downloaded without any problems but I have some trouble to use the new classes in my project.
I know that I have to create -Bridging-Header.h and there I placed the line

```
#import "SSZipArchive.h"
```

But the classes were not be found by the compiler.

Comment: Did you follow the steps here? https://stackoverflow.com/a/39615171/2415822

Comment: You need to add the header path to your project settings, it is not enough to just create a header file.

Comment: The bridging header file is already linked to the project settings. If I store the framework files in a folder and include that one in my project, it's working perfect. So I think it has something to do with the pod integration or an invalid import declaration for the framework headers loaded by CocoaPods.